# How to maintain folder structure when utilizing subdomain

Tags: php

I got a website setup like this: 'public_html/example.org/folder', with a subdomain setup like folder.example.org. That site can be accessed two ways, through example.org/folder or folder.example.org. I'm struggling to keep my file structure consistent.

For example,

```
href="/folder/style.css"
```

works perfect when browsing through example.org/folder, however it completely breaks when browsing through the subdomain, as it will be displayed as 'folder.example.org/folder/style.css'.

I'm thinking this issue should be fixed utilizing the .htaccess file.

Comment: You could certainly use mod_rewrite to change one URL to the other.

Comment: What is the use case for accessing it both ways? Why not just decide which one is the canonical version and redirect the other to it?

Comment: Hey guys. Could you share an example of mod_rewrite so I can take a look? I like being able to access the site both ways

Comment: @Logista Is it an option to simply use relative paths?

Comment: I tried relative paths but doesn't seem to work, it's the issue of the op, putting '/folder/style.css' works if you access the site through example.org/folder, but if you access it through folder.example.org then it will break